# Safari 8 View Post Data

Tags: http

I'm trying to inspect an HTTP post request in the web inspector, however the request only appears very briefly, and I don't get a chance to open it and have a look. It seems to be at an intermediate page (part of a login process), and I'm not sure how to view the request.

Comment: didn't occur to me to look for external program -  thanks